# Invalidate user sessions on multiple servers

Tags: java, grails, amazon-elb, spring-session

I've a Grails application which is deployed on two servers, and the requests to those servers are controlled by AWS load balancer using sticky session.

A user can have concurrent sessions, so the user might be logged in and having a session on Server A, similarly the user might have a session on Server B.

If a user changes their password, I want to invalidate all the sessions of that user. I'm able to do that on one server using *SessionRegistry*. How do I kill the same user's session on the other server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're site is API-driven and you are using a token, all you would have to do is invalidate their token; everytime they are requesting anything via an api or that requires checking their roles, it will check the token in your DB (or the DB of the Identity Management SAAS you use) and removing that would make the very next refresh of the page ask them to log back in.

Comment: So our application is session based driven. And we are using MemCache for session management at AWS end. We're using default configuration of MemCache, which just stores the session ID as a key.

Comment: Invalidate the session ID then : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/session-vs-token-based-authentication/